# Unable to read messages from Kafka topic using console consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created `stream1` in `KSQL` (version 5.0 Beta) with a backing topic `topic1` and `avro` schema. I am able to read all messages on `topic1` using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`.

I then created `stream2` in `KSQL` that's based on `stream1` but with `json` format for the messages and backing topic named `topic2`. I am able to read all the messages on `topic2` using `kafka-console-consumer`

I created `stream3` in `KSQL` based on `stream2` with `json` message format and backing topic named `topic3`. However, I am unable to read the messages on `topic3` using `kafka-console-consumer`.

Using `kafkacat` I get offsets on various partitions on `topic3` but none of the actual messages is being printed.

It looks likes the messages are in the topic but neither `kafkacat` not `kafka-console-consumer` is able to print it.

Tried using `--from-beginning` and `--offset earliest --partition 0` with no luck.

Here are the KSQL statements

```
CREATE STREAM stream1(p_id STRING, location STRING, u_id STRING, r_id STRING, b_id STRING, recorded_dtm STRING, 
v_type STRING, value STRING) WITH (kafka_topic='topic1', value_format='AVRO');

CREATE STREAM stream2 WITH (KAFKA_topic='topic2', VALUE_FORMAT='json', TIMESTAMP='RECORDED_TIMESTAMP') 
AS select P_ID+'-'+LOCATION+'-'+U_ID+'-'+R_ID+'-'+B_ID+'-'+V_TYPE as PARTITION_KEY, 
LOCATION, U_ID, R_ID, V_TYPE, B_ID, STRINGTOTIMESTAMP(recorded_dtm, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as RECORDED_TIMESTAMP, 
P_ID, VALUE, RECORDED_DTM,'NM' as DATA_TYPE 
FROM stream1 PARTITION BY PARTITION_KEY;

CREATE STREAM stream3 WITH (KAFKA_topic='topic3', VALUE_FORMAT='json', TIMESTAMP='RECORDED_TIMESTAMP') 
AS select PARTITION_KEY, LOCATION, U_ID, R_ID, V_TYPE, B_ID, RECORDED_TIMESTAMP, 
P_ID, VALUE, RECORDED_DTM FROM stream2 PARTITION BY PARTITION_KEY;
```

Additional info

In `ksql` if I run `SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';` and run `select * from stream1 limit 5;` or `select * from stream2 limit 5` I see records printed but `select * from stream3 limit 5` does not return any records.

If I run `describe extended stream3` I get

total-messages: 212

which happens to be the number of messages I sent to topic1

Comment: If `kafkacat` doesn't print the messages, then almost certainly there are no messages on the topic. Can you update your question to include steps to reproduce (i.e. each of the `CREATE STREAM` statements that you're running) please? Also, in KSQL do you get output if you `SELECT * FROM stream3;`?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt does that mean the messages were flushed away? If I run `SELECT * FROM stream3` in `KSQL` console and then run the entire process from scratch, I do see messages printed. But after that, shouldn't I be able to use `kafkacat` to retrieve the messages from backing topic?

Comment: Can you update your question to include steps to reproduce (i.e. each of the CREATE STREAM statements that you're running) please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I added the KSQL statements

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was the `Timestamp` on `STREAM3` The value for `recorded_dtm` column sent to messages on topic1 was earlier than the `log.retention.hours` value set in the `kafka server.properties`.

Our `log.retention.hours` value is set to `24 hours` and the recorded_dtm values were earlier than 24 hours. This caused the messages in `STREAM3` and `topic3` to be immediately removed based in the retention policy.